# Django admin - adding actions in Add page view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I have a question about admin: i've defined an admin action 'create pdf', now i can see it in the select widget of the changelist view. 
I'd like to see it as a button in the add page, i've specified both actions_on_bottom and actions_on_top to True, but i see only the usual buttons (save and add another, save and continue, save).

how can i fix it?

thanks, Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions are only registered to the dropdown menus you'll have to add a button with javascript or override the changelist template(s)